# Adobe Flash CS5.5 Actionscript 3 Buttons within movieclips cause swf preview and debugger to freeze

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, freeze, movieclip

To say i am new to actionscript 3.0 is an understatement. But i am still trying to use it anyway. At the moment i am trying to create an interactive movie, with each frame in the main timeline containing a movieclip, and the movieclips containing the choices are the ones with buttons.

The issue here is simple, when the first button comes up the video freezes, and it seems like i can click the button but nothing happens when its clicked.

I have tried searching for a solution but it seems the only thing that comes up are ways to get the player to freeze when a button is clicked, sort of the opposite of what i'm looking for :)

The code at this point is really simple:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

this.Choice1R.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonHandler1);

function ButtonHandler1(e:MouseEvent){
    MovieClip(this.parent as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(3);
}
```

A simple stop(); tag is inside every keyframe in the main timeline to allow the movieclips inside to play, and that's about it. Every layer containing a button at this point looks sort of like this. Choice1R is in this case the instance name. If anyone can think of a reason why this would cause the swf file to freeze, any help would be appreciated.

Note: The sound keeps on playing as normal. No idea why.

Comment: By layer do you mean keyframe?

Comment: @Doorhandle The movieclips consist of 3 layers, one containing the video and one for each button. When the button appears, there is a keyframe in that layer. The main timeline only has one layer, since the only thing it really does is direct to other movieclips.

Comment: Is there any way you can keep the button up but just set visible to false and add the actions to the button from its parent?

Comment: I managed to solve it. Turns out that there was a type error, caused by the fact that Choice1R wasn't instantiated properly. Silly me. Now i have other issues though, issues i will post in another question where there's space for it. Thanks for the help though, i do believe i will have to move the actions into the main timeline after all.

Comment: I'll look at your new question, but instead of main timeline, why not OOP?